# Element present in driver.getPageSource() but getting NoSuchElement Exception in Selenium with java

Tags: automated-testing

[image: HTML]Hi I am working on automation -selenium with java. I need to click on a button which is inside a modal popup and the whole is inside an iframe. I tried the following code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(2);
log.info(driver.getPageSource()); 
driver.findElement(By.className("modal-content")).isDisplayed();
```

I get the element with class "modal-content" in the pagesource but NoSuchElement Exception when i run the automation script. Is there any possible way to find the element?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly add the relevant HTML? I have the suspicion that your modal might live within another sandbox (frame, iframe, window...) but without seeing the markup I can't really help you.

Comment: @Daniel    I have added the screenshot of the html!

Comment: Hi @Sina. Adding the actual code would be much better than a screenshot--code is much more reasonable and answerers could actually try the code when suggesting solutions, which could help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame-preview-c182db");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'Frozen')]")).isDisplayed();
```

Here i'm switching the frame using *ID*.

Comment: The frame id is generated dynamically only the first part- "frame-preview" is static the rest is dynamically generated.

Comment: ok then use, as you was using it ``driver.switchTo().frame(2);``

Comment: Still unable to locate element error.

Comment: Is your frame number is correct?, i mean frame size

Comment: I tried this: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'frame-preview-')]"));

Comment: I tried this and it works..!WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'frame-preview-')]"));
     driver.switchTo().frame(iframe); driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'Frozen')]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the Problem you're facing are your js sandboxes. An iframe loads the entire content of another page into your parent page, including a separate execution environment for Javascript. To access this environment you need to explivitly call driver.switchTo().frame(WEBELEMENT) before you can interact with the elements.

In your case 
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id*='frame-preview']"));
    followed by your element query should work.

If it doesn't try going up your tree and look if you're possibly within a nested iframe. In that case you need to switch step by step from the most outer to your target frame.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to switch from step by step.

Comment: Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

If it is the only `iframe` starting with *frame-preview* locator you can use partial css locator (or xpath - up to you) to explicity state the frame you want to change to:

```
List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("iframe[id^='frame-preview']");
driver.switchTo().frame(iframes.get(INDEX_OF_IFRAME_TO_USE));
```

Then try some more explicit selector for the *modal-content*:

```
WebElement modalContent = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-rec-id='FloatingPanelComponent-modalContainer] div[class='modal-content']");
```

If this results in `NoSuchElementException` you should probably introduce some timeout. Test it by placing a `breakpoint` at the `WebElement modalContent` line. If waiting resolves your issue, introduce an `ExplicitWait`, like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[data-rec-id='FloatingPanelComponent-modalContainer] div[class='modal-content']")));
```

Comment: There are 2 iframes with id starting with "frame-preview"!

Comment: Then capture a `List` of iframes, and use the one that you need. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the responses!